# Ajax call is not working in View(ASP.NET MVC 5). How do I solve it?

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

My actions returns a Json to my view, however, my ajax call can't use this data, so, whole data is put on the browser.

That's my action is my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult InformarPatrocinador()
    {
        //return View("CadastrarFicha");
        /*
        Patrocinador patr = new Patrocinador
        {
            NomeDoPatrocinador = "João",
            Id_Patrocinador = 10000


        };*/

        var db = new FMDBEntities();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return Json(db.Tabela_Participante.
            Select(x => new
            {
                Nome = x.Nome
            }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

That's my view(Where the Ajax Call is)

```html
@model FlowerMorena_WebUI.Models.ViewModelFicha

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "InformarPatrocinador";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Informar Patrocinador</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Patrocinador</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <label> Código do Patrocinador </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Patrocinador.Id_Patrocinador, new { @class = "form-control", id = "IdDoMeuPatr" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <label> Nome do Patrocinador </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Patrocinador.NomeDoPatrocinador, new { @class = "form-control center-block", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", id = "NomePatr" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <input class="btn btn-success" value="Avançar" id="buttonx" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}

<ul id="aLista"></ul>
@section scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#buttonx').on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Ficha/InformarPatrocinador',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        $('aLista').append("<li>" + item.Nome + "<li>")
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
}
```

[That's what I got(Ajax call did nothing))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnklz.png)

Answer (score 0):

are you calling your Action like localhost:0000/Ficha/InformarPatrocinador ?
and if you are doing this then this action will always return the result you have shown in picture.

you should make another post Action like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InformarPatrocinador()
{
}
```

and change your Ajax method to Post

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Ficha/InformarPatrocinador',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                    $('aLista').append("<li>" + item.Nome + "<li>")
                });
            }
        });
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, however, it didn't work either.

Comment: I could solve it by myself. The problem was that my action InformarPatrocinador returned the view and it was called in my jquery script too.

Comment: i am always curious about solutions !